# Strange url on localhost when debugging web app in C#.Net2

Tags: url, asp.net-2.0

http://localhost/XYZ/Client/(S(enlodz55ov4ncafza0gpp045))/Info/Rates.aspx

Does anyway know what **/(S(enlodz55ov4ncafza0gpp045))/** means?

Any help appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's the session identifier if you're using cookieless session state.

See this MSDN article: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa479314.aspx